# PHP TCP Client cannot connect to the server

Tags: php, tcp, client

I have made gathered some examples of connecting the TCP clinet to the server and changed the IP but I don't really know whats the error in my code because it should work and the server is online as well from Gta San Andrease Multiplayer script console, the server is on a localhost from my other pc with ip 192.168.0.11 and the server port is 7777 , here is the client side code from my PHP website:

```
 <?php

  // form submitted
  // where is the socket server?
  $host="192.168.0.11";
  $port = 7777;
  // open a client connection
  echo "1";
  $fp = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $timeout);
  echo "2";
  if (!$fp){
  echo "3";
  $result = "Error: could not open socket connection";
  }
  else
  {
 echo "4";
  // get the welcome message
  fgets ($fp, 7777);
  // write the user string to the socket
  fputs ($fp, $message);
  // get the result
  $result .= fgets ($fp, 7777);
  // close the connection
  fputs ($fp, "END");
  fclose ($fp);
  // trim the result and remove the starting ?
  $result = trim($result);
  $result = substr($result, 2);
  // now print it to the browser
  }
  ?>
  Server said: <b><? echo $result; ?></b>
  <?

  ?>
```

and this is the warning/error:

Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 192.168.0.11:7777 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

Comment: What exactly is the problem? the script dies at a certain point? doesn't work as expected?

Comment: updated my question, read the last part please

Comment: Sounds like there's a firewall somewhere in the mix that's silently dropping packets, rather than responding with a reset.

Comment: I dont understand, you want me to switch off firewall?

Comment: no, but at least make sure that port 7777 is allowed through on both sides (your client and on the server)

Comment: Try to use 'telnet' to check 7777 port on 192.168.0.11. What kind of service is running behind 7777 ?

Comment: it gives me the same error, it takes like about 40 seconds to load the page and then it gives me that error/warning

Comment: @Kamran a samp server is running behind it which runs a pawn script and in that script I've included the TCP server and when I compile the pawn it doesn't give me error so I guess thats not causing me any problem

Comment: 40 seconds is about right for a TCP timeout. Something is ignoring your connection data packets.

Comment: Try it with the firewall off to see if that's the problem, then turn it back on.

Comment: If you have access to the host that is running your server, try telnet 127.0.0.1 7777 If this works, your firewall may be blocking the incoming external connections to this port.

Comment: I think first you need to get sure that your samp server is running. This can be tested locally on your server machine as Hernan said. If it's ok, there is something in the middle.